# Couldn't load Tableau JS API in LWC

Tags: javascript, salesforce, tableau-api, salesforce-lightning, lwc

this is the Tableau JS API  [1]: https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js .I had saved this file as JS and uploaded it as static resource in Salesforce.

This is the LWC JS code to load the script

```js
renderedCallback() {
    if (!this.scriptLoaded) {
      Promise.all([loadScript(this, tableauAPI)])
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Custom scripts loaded");
                this.scriptLoaded = true;
                this.initializeViz();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error loading custom sccripts");
            });
    }
  }
```

whenever I try to load the scripts it always goes to the catch block and I couldn't load the script in LWC

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you imported the static resource. Most static resources are saved as a folder. So if your resource was imported like this: `import tableauAPI from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/tableauAPI";`, then your loadScript may need to look something like this: `Promise.all([loadScript(this, tableauAPI + "/tableau.min.js")])`. Of course you'd need to replace `tableau.min.js` with the actual name of your JS file, but that may fix it for you.